# redirect specific computers to Specific ou

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Helle All,

I am planning to redirect the specific name of the computers to specific OU like as below

```
Condition 1. Name which starts with CMP* need to move to "Com" OU
Condition 2. Name which starts with LTP* need to move to "LTP" OU
```

Please let me know the steps.

Thanks.

Regards,

Ramasamy R S

Comment: There's no feature that you can use in AD that will implement this sort of rule. New computer accounts are put into the Computers container (not actually an OU). You can change this to a different OU, but you can't make it dynamic. If you want this to happen without manual intervention, you'll need to have a scheduled task that does something like Sorcha's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

With Powershell you can do something like this :

```
Get-ADComputer -filter {*} -searchbase "OU=xx,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx"| Where-Object {$_.name -like "CMP*"} | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "ou=Com,dc=xx,dc=xx"
```

`Get-ADComputer` selects the computers of your AD.

`Where-Object` only with their name corresponding to the wildcard

`Move-ADObject` and finally you your computer in the new OU

you can also put replace the where-object by using the filter of the get-ADComputer.